# Uninitialized Constant In rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Im getting an uninitialized constant Chef::Meal error when populating my DB.

Am I doing something wrong in my Models?

Chef Model

```
class Chef < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :meals
end
```

Meals Model

```
class Meals < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :chef
    validates :chef_id, presence: true
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the model name from `Meals` to `Meal`

Answer (score 0):

Your have a `Meals` Model, it should be singular i.e, `Meal`

```
class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :chef
    validates :chef_id, presence: true
end
```

Also see these [**Naming Conventions**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#naming-conventions) for Rails